# How to click on a specific link with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have an integration test. It uses Selenium, from Java. I would like to click on a specific link, which has no ID. All I know about it is that it is in a specific cell in a specific table. The table has an ID.

How can I click on that element using `DefaultSelenium`?

I tried

```
defaultselenium.click("th.tblHeader:nth-child(14) > a:nth-child(1)");
```

because Firefox said that it's the XPath of the element, and I also tried

```
defaultselenium.click("#tableId > thead:nth-child(1) > tr > th.tblHeader:nth-child(14) > a:nth-child(1)");
```

because I don't use XPath very often and I had no idea what I was doing, but I thought that having a unique ID in the equation may help.
Both of them give me "ERROR: Element ... not found" messages.

Comment: Please share the html structure with us, or a link for the page where the element can be found. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not XPath, it's CSS. Vanilla Firefox isn't helpful for extracting XPath from a page, but there are plugins available. Alternatively, Chrome will give you the XPath.